# SQL Syntax Error when executing mysqli_query

Tags: php, mysql, sql, oop, mysqli

I have an PHP registration script with MySQLi and OOP.
But i get an mysql syntax error when executing an query.

```
 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '-mail, ip_register, ip_lastlogin, lastlogin) VALUES ('', Aarivex, ******, ****' at line 1
```

PHP Code:

```
$register_sql = "INSERT INTO users (id, username, password, pin, e-mail, ip_register, ip_lastlogin, lastlogin) VALUES ('', $username, $password, $pin, $email, $ip, $ip, $lastlogin)";
```

Wheres the problem?

Comment: Geez, that's an easy one.

Comment: P.S. Look into parameterized queries.  This is (probably) unsafe as-is.

Comment: Solved my problem. Thx to all!

I must set the 'id' value to 0, change e-mail to email and added the quotes.

Comment: You're welcome @Aarivex glad to have been of help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
...for the right syntax to use near '-mail  
SQL's telling you where error starts ^ the offending character
```

You need to wrap/encapsulate the `e-mail` column in backticks since it contains a hyphen.

SQL figures you want to do math which translates to: `e` minus `mail`

Plus, missing quotes in your values

```
$register_sql = "INSERT INTO users (id, username, password, pin, `e-mail`, ip_register, ip_lastlogin, lastlogin) VALUES ('', '$username', '$password', '$pin', '$email', '$ip', '$ip', '$lastlogin')";
```

Those are strings and must be inside quotes.

- Another option would be to rename your column to `e_mail` using an underscore as you did for some of the other columns. That way, you would not need to use backticks.

---

Look into using one of the following also:

- [**Prepared statements**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php)
- [**PDO with prepared statements**](http://php.net/pdo.prepared-statements).

---

Having used `or die(mysqli_error($con))` to `mysqli_query()` would have signaled the error(s).

`$con` being your DB connection, this could/stand to be different than yours.

- *Adjust accordingly.*

---

**Identifiers** (table/columns)

- More on this topic: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/identifier-qualifiers.html

---

***Tip:***

Try and avoid using hyphens, or spaces or any other character that SQL may complain about, this includes using a space in between words.

I.e.:

```
INSERT INTO your_table (column 1, column-2) <= will cause/throw an error
```

you would need to use backticks:

```
INSERT INTO your_table (`column 1`, `column-2`) <= correct / valid
```

Although spaces are allowed (*yet discouraged*), they too need to be encapsulated in backticks.

Comment: +1 for mentioning the missing quotes. I hadn't gotten that, far.

Answer (score 2):

If you're going to have a dash in a column identifier (which is a bad idea) you *must* wrap it in ticks. Otherwise you are subtracting the value of the `mail` column from the `e` column which not not valid in an INSERT statement.

You're also missing quotes around your string values.

```
$register_sql = "INSERT INTO users (id, username, password, pin, `e-mail`, ip_register, ip_lastlogin, lastlogin) VALUES ('', '$username', '$password', '$pin', '$email', '$ip', '$ip', '$lastlogin')";
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing e-mail fieldname to email OR you need to encompass your that field name with back quotes like this:

```
`e-mail`
```

Answer (score -1):

I suppose your id is set to **Auto Increment**.
If it is just remove the first column from the insert statement and it should work fine.

```
$register_sql = "INSERT INTO users (username, password, pin, e-mail, ip_register, ip_lastlogin, lastlogin) VALUES ($username, $password, $pin, $email, $ip, $ip, $lastlogin)";
```

And yes, change the e-mail field to `e-mail`.